# How to set upload URL from SAPUI5 Controller to UploadCollection control?

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

I am using the UploadCollection  control with instantUpload = true in SAPUI5.
UploadCollection control having uploadUrl Property, But I don't want to give this URL in XML view.
I would like to give this URL by using `**setUploadUrl(sUploadUrl)**` method of UploadCollection control from Controller.js.
Now My question is i don't have upload button because I am using `instantUpload`. then in which event I can write the following for setting upload URL

```
var oFileUploader = sap.ui.getCore().byId("UploadCollection");
            var sUrl = "some URL";
            oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(sUrl);
```

The following code is for UploadCollectionItem in xml view.

```
<UploadCollectionItem
                        documentId="{documentId}"
                        fileName="{fileName}"
                        mimeType="{mimeType}"
                        thumbnailUrl="{thumbnailUrl}"
                        url="{url}"
                        enableEdit="false"
                        enableDelete="false"
                        visibleDelete="false"
                        visibleEdit="false"
                        attributes="{path : 'attributes', templateShareable : 'true'}"
                        statuses="{path : 'statuses', templateShareable : 'true'}"
                        selected="{selected}">
                        <attributes>
                            <ObjectAttribute
                                title="{title}"
                                text="{parts : ['text', 'type'], formatter : '.formatAttribute'}"
                                active="{active}"/>
                        </attributes>
                        <statuses>
                            <ObjectStatus
                                title="{title}"
                                text="{text}"
                                state="{state}"
                                icon="{icon}"
                                iconDensityAware="{iconDensityAware}"
                                textDirection="{textDirection}"/>
                        </statuses>
                    </UploadCollectionItem>
                </items>
            </UploadCollection>
```

How to fix this issue Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try onInit function of your controller. But if you are using routing ( and if you not, you should ), attach an event to pattern match:

```
onInit: function() {            
        this.getRouter().getRoute(/*your route name*/).attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
},

_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
            var oFileUploader = sap.ui.getCore().byId("UploadCollection");
            var sUrl = "some URL";
            oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(sUrl);
}
```